# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException Jboss eap

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have an entity class that looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @XmlAttribute
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

This entity is being persisted by this class:

```
public class MyStarter {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void insertIntodb() {
        final MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.setName("Sample");
        manager.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

However, whenever the persist code gets executed above, I get an exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

To try and fix this, here is me doing a bcktrack of things to verify what works and what does not:

- I have verified that the user connection to the database has write permissions.
- I have verified that a native query, that selects data, can indeed execute from JPA and return back results.
- I have added , type = javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED) to the @PersistanceContext annotation
- I have updated the persistance.xml file to contain these lines:

  ```
  <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Mysource</jta-data-source>

  <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2" />
      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbo" />
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
          value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
          value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
  </properties>
  ```

However, I can still not get rid of the issue. Anything obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Transactional` as below

```
@Transactional
public class MyStarter {
...
```

OR as

```
@Transactional
public void insertIntodb() {
    final MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
    entity.setName("Sample");
    manager.persist(entity);
}
```

This is because, `persist()` guarantees that it will **not** execute an `INSERT/UPDATE` statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries.
Hence, you need a transaction to save the object in db, while using the `persist()`.

In Spring context file you need to add below code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

---

Instead of `persist()` you can use `save()`. The `save()` method can be executed inside or outside of a transaction. Using `save()` is **not** good in a long-running conversation with an extended Session/persistence context.

Comment: what are considered transaction boundaries? outside of the entity class?

Comment: you mean `@Transactional` applied on class? I so, then `@Transactional` is applied to every individual method of your MyStarter class. And Invoking insertIntodb() -> a transaction is started. When insertIntodb() calls another method no new transaction is started, because there is already one. Remember, you cannot use `persist()` outside transaction. It will not be executed.

Comment: ah I see. The oddest part is that I have seen some projects that do not explicitly use that annotation, and call the .persist() method, with no issue.

Comment: Yes, there can be such projects but the transaction management done in that projects would be `declarative` using `<tx:advice /> ` tag and AOP configuration. And it is a good practice.